# How to make Framer Motion only loop animation between initial and animate

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

## Issue:

If I use `transition: {repeat: Infinity}` to animate between `initial` and `animate` it does work fine, but once the item is unloaded `AnimatePresence` keeps it around animating between `animate` and `exit`.

Here is the sample code:

```
<AnimatePresence>
  {isLoading &&
    <motion.div
      transition={{ repeatType: 'reverse', repeat: Infinity }}
      initial={{ opacity: .5 }}
      animate={{ opacity: .8 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

## Question:

How can I only repeat animation between `initial` and `animate` and let the `exit` animation play only once?

## Attempts:

Note: I have tried using `isLoading` in the transition but it doesn't seem to work (it still keeps `Inifite`ly looping between `animate` and `exit`)

```
<AnimatePresence>
  {isLoading &&
    <motion.div
      transition={{ repeatType: 'reverse', repeat: isLoading ? Infinity : 0 }}
      initial={{ opacity: .5 }}
      animate={{ opacity: .8 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Framer motion [supports keyframes](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/##keyframes), and you can also set a transition for each stage the motion element is in (inital, animate, exit). I was able to create the effect you wanted with this code:

```
<AnimatePresence>
    {isLoading && (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0.5 }}
        animate={{

          // Putting values into an array tells framer these are keyframes
          opacity: [0.5, 0.8],

          // Moved transition to be specific to the `animate` stage
          transition: {
            repeat: Infinity,
            repeatType: "reverse",
          },
        }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    )}
  </AnimatePresence>
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crazy-stitch-58phrl) I made with the effect.